# MVC Sending Values to Form

Tags: php, forms

I have been making a site to learn about MVC, I am trying to add a function to the update option. At the moment I have two buttons on each row (one to delete and one to update), when the update button is pressed a form to update the row appears on the right of the screen.

I am trying to pre-populate the form when the user presses the update the button but I dont know how to do that within an MVC. Should I create a function that does this or should I have some PHP at the top of the form to pre-populate?

Any help or advice will be great

**Update Form to be pre-populated**

```
<h2>Update Item!</h2>
    <h4>Fill in the form to update an entry.</h4>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='updateItem' />
            <p>
                <label for="fTitle">Title</label> <input type="text"
                    id="fTitle" name="fTitle" placeholder="title"
                    maxlength="25" required />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="fPrice">Price</label> <input type="text"
                    id="fPrice" name="fPrice" placeholder="price"
                    maxlength="25" required />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="fDescription">Description</label> <input type="text"
                    id="fDescription" name="fDescription" placeholder="description"
                    maxlength="500" required />
            </p>

            <p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Update button in the View receiving the row ID for the button**

```
            $update = file_get_contents( "templates/updateButton.php");
            $HTMLItemList = "";
            foreach ( $this->model->itemList as $row ) 
                    $HTMLItemList .= "<li><strong>" . $row ["title"] . ": </strong>" . "€" .$row ["price"] . "<blockquote>" . 
                        $row ["description"] .  " " . str_replace("value2replace", $row['id'], $delete) . 
                        str_replace("value2replace", $row['id'], $update) . "</blockquote></li>";
```

**Update Button**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='updateStart' />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="hidden" id="fId" name="fId" value="value2replace"> 
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a question I've struggled with before, and still haven't found a satisfactory solution for. How I've seen it done is that your Controller passes down the data to the view that contains your form, and then you use PHP echo statements to fill in the data automatically.

I've also seen a counter approach where each form is an Object, so for instance:

```
class ItemForm{
    public function render(Item $item = null){
        //create form and fill in data if $item is not null
    }
```

Basically the render function will decide whether to fill in information for you or not, depending on it Item is null or not.

Personally, I like the class version better, just because then you can use it in various places if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look into adding your code, I have been looking at the `file_get_contents` function as well and trying to send database values into a template and then retrieving its contents

Comment: Never thought of use file_get_contents in that way for forms. That's a pretty cool idea. Would you have a base .html file that you would replace values in once you got the string contents back?

Comment: Yes I think so, So i would have and `update.html` form and then I would use the file_get_contents ("update.html+SomeDBValue") to fill in the form

Comment: That's an intriguing possibility. I'll have to look into it myself. Good suggestion

Comment: Just wondering if you had any look using the file_get_contents to pre populate a form? havnt had a chance to look into it yet

Comment: I have not had the opportunity quite yet. I am looking to try it out on our next code process, but it might be a little while before I look at it. If you try it out, let me know.